# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `work_permits` where `user_id` = ?) using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting error please help me how can i resolve this issue ? thanks.

please check error

https://flareapp.io/share/LPdjyyz5

**controller**

```
public function permitBranch(Request $request, $permitbranchId){
   // current date
   $date = date("Y/m/d");
   $userId = User::where('mf_branch_id', $permitbranchId)->pluck('id');
    
   $permit_report = WorkPermit::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
   $data = [
      'permitReports' => $permit_report,
      'date' => $date,
   ];
       
   return  view('cms.report.work_permit_report_list', $data);
}
```

Comment: try accessing `$userId` by `dd($userId);` and check if it returns anything

Comment: Please guide me if the work permit does not have user id effect then don't give error

Comment: @zubairmalik why are you not using relationship that would be helpful for you to handle that if the user_id not exist then don't skip that Instead of querying in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually you are passing array by using pluck

```
   $userId = User::where('mf_branch_id', $permitbranchId)->pluck('id');
```

it returns the array  like this (key is the index of the item. auto incremented value):

```
[
    1 => "name1",
    2 => "name2",
    .
    .
    .
    100 => "name100"
]
```

try it by using first() if you are fetching single record or if its multiple ID's then use whereIn Here

```
 $permit_report = WorkPermit::whereIn('user_id', $userId)->get();
```

if single Record

```
     $userId = User::where('mf_branch_id', $permitbranchId)->firstOrFail();
     $permit_report = WorkPermit::where('user_id', $userId->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

**[`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)** method returns an array, change your code :

```
$userId = User::where('mf_branch_id', $permitbranchId)->firstOrFail();
    
$permit_report = WorkPermit::where('user_id', $userId->id)->get();
```